# Can't hide keyboard on fragment's onDestroyView()

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a problem, I want to hide the keyboard when the fragment is off the screen.

```
override fun onDestroyView() {
    view?.findFocus()?.hideKeyboard()
    super.onDestroyView()
}

internal fun View.hideKeyboard() {
    clearFocus()
    val imm = context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
}
```

It works when I replace one fragment with another, but it doesn't works when I go back to the previous activity. What can be done to handle this case?

Comment: And what happens? Does it continue showing or freezes or exception casts? Is `onDestroyView()` called?

Comment: @CoolMind focus isn't null but other activity is currently opened and hideKeyboard() has no effect.